# Is this "imperative" corrrect? What is dropping the subject called, if anything?

Tags: grammar, subjects, imperatives

I was reading through this Git Commit Message Conventions document for a project and discovered what I think to be an improper recommendation to use imperative mood.

First, if you're not familiar with Git, here is a little background. Git is source code management software. When you make a change to your code you "commit" the code to the repository. When you "commit" you need to include a message explaining what the "commit" does or changed.

The [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QrDFcIiPjSLDn3EL15IJygNPiHORgU1_OOAqWjiDU5Y/edit?pli=1#), [based on this blog post](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3308646748/writing-git-commit-messages), says to use imperative, but the example does not seem to be imperative. Instead it just seems like a fragment. In fact the blog post says that the message should describe what will happen if the commit (the set of changes) is applied.

It seems weird for it to be imperative:

> [You,] rename the iVars to remove the common prefix.
>
> [Let it] rename the iVars to remove the common prefix.

When this really what it should mean:

> [This commit will] rename the iVars to remove the common prefix.
>
> [Applying this commit will] rename the iVars to remove the common prefix.

I have two questions:

1. Am I correct that imperative is the wrong grammatical construct?
2. Is there a grammatical name for dropping the subject, as in the latter example?

Comment: Please [edit] this to separate out the quotes with the > symbol. Otherwise it's very hard to understand.

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of *conversational deletion*, where the beginning part of a sentence might be omitted when it can be considered to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is indeed the "imperative", and I see this use of it as analogous to the way that math formulas or arithmetic procedures are commonly expressed; each line of code in a process is equivalent to one step of an arithmetic problem. Things like "Add 1 and 2. (Then) Divide by 3" or "Put down 6 and carry 2." The imperative here isn't addressed to any particular person, but describing the steps that have to be taken to achieve a desired result. In this case, the steps are to be carried out by a mechanical "computer" rather than a human one, but the convention remains the same. In fact, programming is often conceptualized as giving orders to the computer; hence the name of the "imperative programming" paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think OP's "programmer's comment" message format is really "imperative" in that sense. It's the same basic mode as the kind of inline comments coders sometimes write...

> myvalue = myvalue + 1;     // **increment x**
>    errorcode=validate(x);  // **check x is valid**
>   etc., etc.

...where obviously the bolded comments aren't imperative instructions to a future code maintenance worker. Effectively, they simply *restate what the preceding code does*.

If you *have* to imagine a syntactic "subject" for my examples, I suppose you could say it's the machine that will eventually execute the code (or the compiler producing machine-code from the human-readable version above). But that's all a bit vague.

It's easier to simply imagine an elided ***What this*** [line of code] **does is**... before the comment - or in OP's context, ***What this amendment does is...***